# How can I find two vectors that are orthogonal to three given vectors?

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

For example, let  $u = (2,1,-4,0)$, $v = (-1,-1,2,2)$, $w = (3,2,5,4)$, here we start by fixing $v$ as a fixed point so as to get a cross product $uv \times uw$ ....but how can get the cross product in 4D, please can I get a help

Answer (score 1):

A vector $x = (x_1, x_2 x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ is orthogonal to these three vectors if and only if its coordinates are a solution of the linear system
$$
 \left\{
  \begin{matrix}
    2x_1 &  +x_2 & -4x_3 &       & = 0, \\
    -x_1 &  -x_2 & +2x_3 & +2x_4 & = 0, \\
    3x_1 & +2x_2 & +5x_3 & +4x_4 & = 0.
  \end{matrix}
 \right.
$$
Notice the first equation states that $u \cdot x = 0$, the second statest that $v \cdot x = 0$ and the third states that $w \cdot x = 0$. So all you have to do is to solve this system. (Also notice that we have the trivial solution $(0,0,0,0)$, which corresponds to the fact that the zero vector is orthogonal to every vector.)